# testdisk utility reports nonexistent files from a exFAT drive used with Windows - why?

Tags: linux, windows, unicode, character-encoding, testdisk

I tried to recover lost files from an exFAT thumb drive with the `testdisk` package on linux. It was very good at finding deleted files. However as I went through the entries, I saw weird entries. The program claimed there were dozens of both present and deleted files with unreadable file names and humoungous file size as well as outlandish timestamps.

For example one entry read `79862082558814991`bytes, `2-Apr-1911` and filename `,~WM-*'? M-kxfM-'D^^Q謁懫䞭鵣ㄆ冚୩鳼묁쐚쵡૪댷腁濬`. The names of invalid entries were garbled text, foreign languages and emojis. What was interesting was that some of the timestamps were before the unix epoch.

The weird entries were not on the root of the drive. They were only on some folders. Also files with only alphanumeric characters displayed fine.

My questions are:

1. What is the cause of this phenomenon? Is testdisk mistakenly picking up random leftover bytes as 'deleted files'? Or are some files created on Windows just not suitable for Linux?
2. Do Linux and Windows actually use different encodings/rulesets for their filenames? If so, what happens if a file whose name is valid on one OS which is not on the other is sent to the hostile OS? Do they all turn into gibberish like this?

p.s. All files' content was encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

(1) File scavengers/carvers look for patterns that look like they might have once been files.  That's necessary because the files are, by definition, no longer available normally.  Sometimes things that aren't files match some of the heuristics and you get false positives like that.

(2) In my experience, most filesystems use a particular encoding everywhere, either as part of the spec, or implied.

For example, many early filesystems implied ASCII because that's all there was.

NTFS specifies Unicode and the UCS-2 encoding (16-bit fixed-width characters).

I'm not sure if the the various Linux extended filesystems fall into "implied" or "explicit", but in practice, it's Unicode and UTF-8, or perhaps ASCII in very old kernels.  The actual file names are a sequence of bytes without interpretation, beyond NUL (zero).  It's up to display routines to interpret those bytes as characters.  Those display routines are mostly in userland -- for example, the `ls(1)` utility, and the terminal emulator in use.

What a system does when it encounters an invalid character varies.  As a very general rule, historically, Unix-derived systems tried to make it work and/or didn't notice in the first place (possibly with very confusing results for the user), while Microsoft-derived systems return an error when they notice, or act strangely if they don't.